# Add encrypt hook to mkinitcpio to arch linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mkinitcpio

i want to enable encrypt hook. 
Regulary, you go with nano /etc/mkinitcpio.conf  and add the encrypt hook as archwiki says.
I want to automate that step with bash commands.

`mkinitcpio -A encrypt` add the hook

How can i save it in the default file and with `mkinitcpio -p linux` load the encrypt hook too?

Answer (score 1):

You've got them reversed.

The configuration file **is** the automation option. The `-A` flag is only to update a single images.

So if you want hooks to fire by default you need to add it to the `HOOKS` array in the configuration file, like the Arch Wiki says.

If you want to do that without opening a text editor for some reason you can do that with something like `sed`, but honestly it's easier to just use a text editor.